# ionic 2, refresh a modal page with 2 or more logos

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal page called after the splashscreen closed.
It´s a page for sponsor. From the API comes Logo (imagem) and some text (texto).
The modal close automatically after 3000 ms 
At first i put the delay code inside the constructor, and it´s work fine.
With one sponsor, there are no problems, mas with 2 or more logos, don´t work.

It´s only show the last logo, even i put a delay to refresh the screen.

How to show the 2 or more logos for 3s?

How to refresh the view?

patrocinio.html

```
<ion-content padding class="fundo-titulo">

  <div style="margin-top:40%">
      <br/>
      <img src="http://example.com/api/imagens/Patrocinios/{{imagem}}" width="90%">
      <br /> 
      <h3 text-center>{{ texto }}</h3>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

patrocinio.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Conexao } from '../../providers/conexao';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-patrocinio',
  templateUrl: 'patrocinio.html',
})
export class Patrocinio {

  public patrocinios: any;
  public tempo: string;
  public imagem: string;
  public texto: string;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public loading: LoadingController,
    public viewCtrl: ViewController,
    public conexaoServico: Conexao) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let loader = this.loading.create({
     // spinner: 'ios',
     // content: 'Carregando ...',
    });

    loader.present().then(() => {
      this.conexaoServico.getSponsors('1').subscribe((data) => {
        this.patrocinios = data.Patrocinios;
        console.log(this.patrocinios);
        console.log(this.patrocinios.length);
      });
      loader.dismiss();
    });
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log(this.patrocinios);
    console.log(this.patrocinios.length);

    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < this.patrocinios.length; i++) {

      this.imagem = this.patrocinios[i].Imagem;
      this.texto = this.patrocinios[i].Texto;
      console.log(this.imagem);

      //this.navCtrl.resize;

      var delayInMilliseconds = 3000;
      console.log('aqui')
      setTimeout(function () {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
        //viewCtrl.dismiss();
      }, delayInMilliseconds);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic error looping inside ionViewDidEnter.  What you want to do is to call a function at the delayInMilliseconds period to update your modal.  This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-go-through-sponsors) works but is possibly not the best way to do this.

See the critical code below:

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div>{{sponsor}}</div>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
export class HomePage {
  sponsor : string = '';
  sponsors :string[] = ['hello', 'world'];
  index : number = 0;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    let intervalHandle = setInterval(()=> {
      this.sponsor = this.sponsors[this.index];
      this.index++;

      if(this.index == this.sponsors.length)
      {
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);
      }
    },2000);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Philip. Solved the question, but i have last one wwith this module: it´s a modal page, 
and after the last sponsor's logo appears (plus the delay time), this page will be closed. When I put the viewCtrl.dismiss () after the clearInterval (intervalHandle), the logo is shown and soon thereafter, without the delay time. How can I solve this? Ty again

Comment: Sorry, I'll explain more clearly. The sponsors page is a modal page.
I use this.viewCtrl.dismiss () after the clearInterval (intervalHandle), which is the end of the loop. But the last sponsor appears and the page closes. I need to put a delay before it's dismiss the view.

Comment: `setTimeOut(()=> {this.viewCtrl.dismiss(); },1000);`

Comment: Ty again. Perfect.